# serviceworker en angular universal

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0

Estoy tratando de usar services worker con angular universal , todo bien ,excepto por una cosa , tengo mi archivo client.js el cual es el archivo minimizado de angular.js

Este es mi index.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <base href="/">
  <title>Universal</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').then(function(registration) {
      // Registration was successful
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }).catch(function(err) {
      // registration failed :(
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <demo-app></demo-app>

</body>
</html>
```

mi sw-precache.config es el siguiente

```
module.exports = {
  staticFileGlobs: [
    'dist/**.html',
    'dist/client.js',
    'bower_components/**/*.css',
    'bower_components/**/*.js'
  ],
  maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes:4200000,
  root: 'dist',
  stripPrefix:'dist/',
  navigateFallback:'/index.html'
};
```

Cachea todo , hasta el client.js, sin embargo cuando en el navegador ingreso , me trae todos los archivos registrados en la cache del serviceworker, excepto el client.js ,pues me sale un error diciendo que se excedio la memoria(Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Quota exceeded.) client.js pesa 3.7 mb.

estoy usando jit para compilar pues aún no he logrado implementar aot , para reducir el tamaño del archivo , ni prepack(xmlhttprequest no es soportado) ,que alternativas hay para solucionar este caso? ,